# Color management: how do I make Gimp handle gamma conversion in this png file?

Tags: gimp, color-conversion

This image is shown as an apple in Gimp, although if gamma is handled correctly it should show a pear.

[image: Pear]

What steps should I take in Gimp to make it handle the gamma correctly? I've tried with the default color management settings. It seems Gimp just assumes the png is in sRGB and does no conversion at all?
I'm using Gimp version 2.10.2 on linux (arch)

see https://superuser.com/questions/579216/why-does-this-png-image-display-differently-in-chrome-firefox-than-in-safari-a/579220

Comment: Interesting - Photoshop says it's in Adobe 98, but also ignores the gamma. Safari, Preview & Finder QuickLook all display it correctly. Exiftool says Gamma : 50